# CREATE TABLE gives errors 4145 and 102

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I'm in the process of trying to import a CSV into SQL.  The CSV is very large 4g, so this is really the only option for query against the data, i believe.

I've gotten to the point where I've created a new database and now trying to create the table that will hold the information.

I've run the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Provider_NPI
(NPI INT,
Entity Type Code INT,
Replacement NPI INT,
Employer Identification Number (EIN) INT,
```

After the INT, it goes on for 300+ plus headings, but errors on three different ones with a `MSG 4145, Level 15, State 1, line X´ error.  i've listed them out

```
Error:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'Code'.
```

For this line:  `Replacement NPI INT,`

The line above this is `Entity Type Code INT,`

```
Error:
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'U'.
```

for this line:  `Provider Business Mailing Address Telephone Number VARCHAR(75),`

```
Error:
Provider Business Practice Location Address Telephone Number VARCHAR(75),
```

for this line:  `Provider Business Practice Location Address Telephone Number VARCHAR(75),`

Can anyone help me out on determine what is wrong?  i believe it might have to do with some of the heading names?

Comment: Are you allowed to have spaces in column names like that? Doesn't there need to be brackets around the identifier in that case?

Comment: I'm a total noob at SQL so I'm guessing you mean..

[Entity Type Code] INT,

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: Your guess is right, did you read the documentation for [`CREATE TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)? If so, you will see the statement that table names "must follow the rules for identifiers". The documentation on [identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) explains what format table or column names can be in.

Comment: Looks like that was it..   I updated all the column headings to be enclosed with [ ] and it worked..  I did get the following "Warning: The table "Provider_NPI" has been created, but its maximum row size exceeds the allowed maximum of 8060 bytes. INSERT or UPDATE to this table will fail if the resulting row exceeds the size limit."

It sounds informational.. Pondlife, i didn't read that documentation, I was following a few other links I found from Googling but I'll check them out.. thank you..

Comment: Prior to taking off with importing the actual data from the CSV file. I want to ask if there is anything specific I need to account to ensure the data comes in correctly.

The fields are separated by commas (,) and each field value has double quotes around it (" ").  Below is the query I'm planning to run  What I don't want to happen is for the double quotes to be included within the field value.

example:  "Provider Name","Provider Street Address"
Should go into those columns as
My Provider in Provider Name and 1234 Elm St into Provider Street Address.  Leaving off the double quotes cont'..

Comment: To import data from CSV
BULK
INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column names can have spaces (and parens) in them but only if you put them in brackets.

```
CREATE TABLE Provider_NPI
(NPI INT,
[Entity Type Code] INT,
[Replacement NPI] INT,
[Employer Identification Number (EIN)] INT)
```

Comment: Ansi quoting (using `"`) should be preferred. Or even better: use column names that don't require quoting.

Comment: Sometimes it's nice to have "formatted" names.  Personally I like using []s for this type of thing since that is a fairly standard syntax within SQL Server.  []s are used for anything that isn't a literal basically.

Answer (score 0):

Bernie helped solved this one but I've run into additional issues with the CSV file and have been away on vacation, so I'm back now working to resolve.

I've successfully created the database and table which has all the column headings with the correct data types and lengths set.  i.e. varchar(50) or INT..  The issue I'm running into now is the import of the data from the CSV file.  Its given me msg 4868 error, which I've pin point to issues with the bulk insert i'm attempting to use and double quotes around all the data.

As I said there are 300+ column headings and 100,000 + rows.  All data, numeric, string, and dates are enclosed with double quotes " ".  It looks like a format file is needed and I'm in the process of creating but running into an issue with the instructions at http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;132463

The data looks like "1231231","name 1","address","zip","555-555-5555","","","2nd address","fax","",""

The data continues on with some fields having data surrounded and others empty with just the quotes.  The article indicates using dummy rows to remove the quotes, which I can but it appears it would require a great amount of manual editing of the format file after it is created.

Is there a way to create the format file that will allow me to use it to remove the double quotes on import of the data?  I'm at a loss and really would like to get this solved.

Comment: Yep, I would create a new post